# How to toggle multiple images when i hit the buttons in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to toggle multiple images when i hit the buttons.
For example, if I hit the button called "a", I want to display the image called "a'".

[image]

Comment: please add your code has a snippets instead of the screenshoot please (use the `<>` button in the editor or indent by `4 spaces`)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output. Post CODE, not images of code

Comment: In addition to posting the javascript code (not as a screenshot), you should also post your HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to toggle an element when clicking on another

```js
let clickable = document.getElementsByClassName("click")
let togglable = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle")

function hideAllToggleable() {
  // for each togglable hide it
  for (let toggle of togglable) {
    toggle.style.display = "none"
  }
}
// hide them by default
hideAllToggleable()

// on each clickable
for (let click of clickable) {
  // add an event on click
  click.addEventListener('click', e => {
    let visible = document.getElementById("t" + e.target.dataset.show).style.display === 'block'
  
    // hide everything
    hideAllToggleable()
    
    if (! visible) {
      // show the one we want to show
      document.getElementById("t" + e.target.dataset.show).style.display = "block"
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="click" data-show="1">click me to show 1</div>
<div class="click" data-show="2">click me to show 2</div>
<div class="click" data-show="3">click me to show 3</div>
<div class="click" data-show="4">click me to show 4</div>
<div class="click" data-show="5">click me to show 5</div>

<div class="toggle" id="t1">1</div>
<div class="toggle" id="t2">2</div>
<div class="toggle" id="t3">3</div>
<div class="toggle" id="t4">4</div>
<div class="toggle" id="t5">5</div>
```

I used [`datasets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset), custom attribute you can use as you want to store data on element

Answer (score 0):

have a loop using querySelectorAll

```
document.querySelectorAll("[id^=tf1]").forEach(function() { // any button
  this.addEventListener("click",function() {
    var id = this.id.substring(1).replace("-","_");
    document.querySelectorAll("[id^=f1]").forEach(function() { // all elements  
      this.style.display="none";
    });
    document.getElementById(id).style.display="none"?"block":"none"; // toggle the specific element
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to create a global variable to mark the image which is chosen

```
let chosenImage;
document.querySelectorAll("[id^=tf1]").forEach(function() {
   click.addEventListener('click', e => {
      if(chosenImage != null){
         chosenImage.display = 'none'
      }
      this.display = this.display === 'block'? 'none' :'block'
   }
}
```

Comment: That is not needed. Also it seems each set needs its own var then